# put the application on trace

Tags: windows

İ have a windows application. I made it in v.s 2008 with c#. I want to put it on trace when i m installing it. like windows messenger, yahoo messenger etc...

Comment: You mean the Taskbar Notification Area?

Comment: Yes Remus. I want to put it on the taskbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess that by '[trace](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/10/54831.aspx)' you mean the [Taskbar Notification Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511448.aspx). To add an icon in the notification area you use a [NotificationIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) component. To react to user interacting with your icon you add event handlers or set the [ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.contextmenu.aspx) to your notification icon. The MSDN help for the NotificationIcon has a sample on how to achieve most common tasks like hiding the form on close and activate it back on notification icon click.